# Installing gcc 3.4.6 using gcc 4.2 on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, gcc

I am trying to install gcc 3.4.6 on Mac OS X 10.6.8; To install gcc 3.4.6 I needed a compiler and somehow I was able to install gcc-4.2. Now using 4.2 I am trying to install 3.4.6 which throws an error as

```
./gcc.c:716: warning: string length ‘2483’ is greater than the length ‘509’ ISO C90 compilers are required to support
./gcc.c:723: warning: string length ‘636’ is greater than the length ‘509’ ISO C90 compilers are required to support
./gcc.c:906: warning: string length ‘529’ is greater than the length ‘509’ ISO C90 compilers are required to support
./gcc.c:924: warning: string length ‘608’ is greater than the length ‘509’ ISO C90 compilers are required to support
./gcc.c:1095: error: expected expression before ‘,’ token
./gcc.c:1506: warning: string length ‘833’ is greater than the length ‘509’ ISO C90 compilers are required to support
./gcc.c: In function ‘main’:
./gcc.c:6261: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments
make[1]: *** [gcc.o] Error 1
make: *** [all-gcc] Error 2
```

Any help on why am getting this error and what is the solution is appreciated.

Comment: "Now using 4.2 I am trying to install 3.4.6 which throws an error as [...]" *How* are you trying to install it? What flags are you providing to `gcc-4.2`?

Comment: Why on earth do you want such a museum piece running on your current system?

Answer (score 0):

You can NOT using a new version gcc to compile a very old one because it will cause tons of syntax errors. Maybe you should find a precomipled version.

Comment: Oldish GCC was writen in sort of least common C features, to be compiled by really horrific C compilers (yes, Sun, I'm thinking of you), so that shouldn't really be a problem.